# closing UISearchBar after showing results

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

In a `UITableView` I have  a hidden `UISearchBar` as default behaviour at app launch. Later, if the user needs to search for a term, there is `UIButton` action that shows the `UISearchBar` and the keyboard.
The problem I have is that after executing the search, I don't know how to cancel the search or to close the `UISearchBar`. If the user clicks on the keyboard Search button, the keyboard disappears, that is OK, but if the user clicks on the `UISearchBar` Cancel button, anything happen.

This is my code to hide the `UISearchBar`:

```
- (void)hideSearchBar {

    CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    if (self.tableView.bounds.origin.y < 44) {
        newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + self.searchBar.bounds.size.height;
        self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;

    }
}
```

And this my code to show the UISearchBar and the keyboard:

```
- (IBAction)showSearchBar:(id)sender {


    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Use `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:` delegate method of `UISearchBar` and call `hideSearchBar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

Above is delegate method of `UISearchBar`, it's use for manage `UISearchBar` when you press on cancel button.

Put you stuff of code as per your requirement.

Such like

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.text = @""; // clear text of search
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; // keyBoard is hide
    [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES]; // remove cancel button from searchBar
   // Etc..
}
```

**EDITED :**

You can declare and access `UISearchBar` such like,

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> // add delegate and datasource to .h file

@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

And **.m** file  creation of `UISearchBar`

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,38.0f,320.0f,0.0f)]; // set frame as you want.
[self.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(93/255.f) green:(156/255.f) blue:(13/255.f) alpha:1.0f]; // set color as you want.
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, but I am logging your method and it is never called...

Comment: This is my interface part: @interface ToDoItemsTableViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>

Comment: set `self.searchBar.delegate = self;`

Comment: My code is correct because i'm working with it... so may be problem from your side.. ok try with `[self.tableView addSubview:self.searchBar];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47476/discussion-between-ipatel-and-mvasco)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Use `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:` delegate method of `UISearchBar` and call `hideSearchBar`

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar { 

    [searchBar setText:@""];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self hideSearchBar];
}
```

Add

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, but I am logging your method and it is never called...

Comment: did you set delegate of `UISearchBar`? if no set it like self.searchBar.delegate = self;

Comment: this way and where? self.searchBar.delegate = self;

Comment: if `self.searchBar` is an `IBOutlet` set delegate in viewDidLoad or in Xib

Comment: if `self.searchBar` is a `@property` then set delegate after initialisation.

Comment: I have put it in viewDidlLoad.

Comment: don't forget to add `UISearchBarDelegate` in .h